# Why does a global list variable is updated in global scope inside a function without using global line?

Tags: python, list, scope, global

I've faced an global issue recently and I have no idea for this behavior in python:

```
# declaring some global variables
variable = 'peter'
list_variable_1 = ['a','b']
list_variable_2 = ['c','d']

def update_global_variables():
    """without using global line"""
    variable = 'PETER' # won't update in global scope
    list_variable_1 = ['A','B'] # won't get updated in global scope
    list_variable_2[0]= 'C' # updated in global scope surprisingly this way
    list_variable_2[1]= 'D' # updated in global scope surprisingly this way

update_global_variables()

print('variable is: %s'%variable) # prints peter
print('list_variable_1 is: %s'%list_variable_1) # prints ['a', 'b']
print('list_variable_2 is: %s'%list_variable_2) # prints ['C', 'D']
```

Why did `list_variable_2` is updated in global scope while the other variables did not?

Comment: The *variable* isn't updated. The *object the variable is referring to is mutated*.

Comment: Read the following: https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html

Answer (score 0):

You haven't defined list_variable_2 in the function and python is therefore unable to find that variable in that scope. If this happens python searches outside its scope.

The order which it searches is as follows

1. Local: If you refer to x inside a function, then the interpreter
   first searches for it in the innermost scope that’s local to that
   function.
2. Enclosing: If x isn’t in the local scope but appears in a
   function that resides inside another function, then the interpreter
   searches in the enclosing function’s scope.
3. Global: If neither of
   the above searches is fruitful, then the interpreter looks in the
   global scope next.
4. Built-in: If it can’t find x anywhere else, then
   the interpreter tries the built-in scope.

Source
https://realpython.com/python-namespaces-scope

Answer (score 0):

Please, acknowledge with LEGB rule:
https://realpython.com/python-scope-legb-rule/

in your case list_variable_1 within function is new list in local namespace
but for list_variable_2 you are accessing each element of list_variable_2 and changing it.